# How do write a dispatch table for methods?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get rid of the `if` statements at the end of a subroutine I'm writing to handle `SELECT` queries:

```
sub select_query {
  my ($params, $query, $return_type) = @_; 
  my $qh = $dbx->prepare($query);
  my $param_count = 1;
  foreach my $param (@$params) {
    $qh->bind_param($param_count++, $param);
  }
  $qh->execute;

  if ($return_type eq 'fetchrow_array') {
    return $qh->fetchrow_array;
  }
  if ($return_type eq 'fetchall_arrayref') {
    return $qh->fetchall_arrayref;
  }
  ... AND SO ON ...
}
```

I'm familiar with the idea of a dispatch table to call different subroutines. What code could I use to efficiently call the various dbi methods on the $qh handle?

Comment: you can just do $qh->$return_type

Comment: Even with `use strict`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is `$qh->$return_type(...)`.

If you wish to validate, you can use a trivial lookup table.

```
my @valid_return_types = qw( fetchrow_array ... );
my %valid_return_types = map { $_ => 1 } @valid_return_types;

die "..." if !$valid_return_types{$return_type};
```

Comment: I'm using `use strict` so I don't think this would work.

Comment: Yup, you are right.

I should have second guessed myself.

Comment: Method calls and `\&$name` are exempt from strict refs checks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the dispatch table after creating the statement handle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:mysql:localhost", 'user', 'password');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from user");
my $return_type = 'fetchall_arrayref';

my %dispatch  = (fetchall_arrayref => sub {return $sth->fetchall_arrayref},
                 fetchrow_array    => sub {return $sth->fetchrow_array});


$sth->execute;
print Dumper $dispatch{$return_type}->();
```

**UPDATE:**
Actually, let me make a correction.  You can, if you wish, define the dispatch table prior creating the statement handle.

```
my %dispatch  = (fetchall_arrayref => sub {return $_[0]->fetchall_arrayref},
                 fetchall_hashref  => sub {return $_[0]->fetchall_hashref('User')},
                 fetchrow_array    => sub {return $_[0]->fetchrow_array});

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:mysql:localhost", 'root', 'password') or die;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from user");

foreach my $type (qw(fetchall_arrayref fetchall_hashref fetchrow_array)) {
    $sth->execute;
    print Dumper $dispatch{$type}->($sth);
}
```

Comment: This would work but I was wondering if there might be some super concise way that's easy on the eye. I'll accept the answer if nothing better comes along.

Comment: Well, you did ask about using a dispatch table and this is the most concise way I can think of to set that up.  But if you want something shorter, then use the non-dispatch table method that ikegami showed.